# How to update an Excel column?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have two excel files which are Table1 and Table 2 as shown:

[image]

All the data have it unique id, and i wish to update the cost column in table 1 according to data in table 2.

May I know how can I update the "Cost" column in table 1 according to the "Invoice id" in table 2 automatically?

[image]

I have tried with the coding below and unluckily seems no work, no matching occur, Table 1 cost still remain as table 1 cost. I have check with the cell type for both invoice id and cost column in both excel and it shown they are identical which is all of them are int.
However i still cant figure out where is the part of wrong.

```
# Import library which going to use

import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
book1 = 'Book1.xlsx'
book2 = 'Book2.xlsx'

Book1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(book1)
book1_firstsheet = Book1['template']

Book2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(book2)
book2_firstsheet = Book2['template']

for book1_rownumber in range (2,book1_firstsheet.max_row):
    book1_invoice= book1_firstsheet.cell(row=book1_rownumber,column=3).value
    book1_cost=book1_firstsheet.cell(row=book1_rownumber,column=4).value
    for book2_rownumber in range (2,book2_firstsheet.max_row):
        book2_invoice= book2_firstsheet.cell(row=book2_rownumber,column=3).value
        book2_cost=book2_firstsheet.cell(row=book2_rownumber,column=4).value
        if book1_invoice == book2_invoice:
            book1_cost = book2_cost

new_file= "new_workbook.xlsx"

Book1.save(new_file)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have tried.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sure, i have update my question with the coding that i tried before, thank for remind ya!

Comment: @martineau thank you for the remind and i have update my attempt on the solution that i done before, hope that is specific and if there are still any blur please do remind me, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Change your last line (book1_cost = book2_cost) after the if condition to the following

```
book1_firstsheet.cell(row=book1_rownumber,column=4).value = book2_firstsheet.cell(row=book2_rownumber,column=4).value
```

and it should work, in my opinion

Comment: its work after i change my last line, appreciate with you help Ashish, wish you have a great day

Comment: @Sodium : I am glad it worked, If you could accept it as an answer, that would be great